# How to implement a login functionality without a database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I want to create a login page for my project and validate a user without using any database.How can i do this? Is it possible with cache? Please guide me.

Comment: you can check hardcoded username and password on controller and  allowed user to access a page or like this, but why you need this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HTTP Basic Authentication ? For reference, here is the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication).

And an example :

```
before_filter :authenticate

protected

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "foo" && password == "bar"
  end
end
```